# is there ever a reason to use "is"?

Tags: python, syntax, operators, comparison-operators

Instead of "=="?  I know what "is" is, it is comparing the identity of the variable.  But when would you ever want to do that?  All it has ever done for me is cause problems.  After using it for a while (because I felt it made my code more readable), I am not declaring war on "is".

Does anyone use it for something that "==" wouldn't do?  I don't understand why they didn't make 'is' the same thing as '==', like they made 'and' the same as '&&' etc.  If someone wanted the pointer, they just have to say "id(x) == id(y)" and we wouldn't have this confusion.

It's one of the "gotcha's" in python that I don't understand, and trip a lot of newbies up.  The reason I think it trips people up is that they don't get why it would do an identity comparison.  What is the point(er)?

Edit:
Thanks for the great answers.  I think what new people should take away is "always use '==' unless you know what you are doing"!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason.

When you want to compare *object-identity* ("same object") and not *object-equality* ("same value"). In almost all cases `==` (*object-equality*) is the correct operator to use. (As pointed out in the comments, the trivial case I skipped entirely is the `x is None` idiom -- `None` is the sole inhabitant of `NoneType`.)

One case for *object-identity* is an *identity-cache/dictionary* which is a common pattern in some proxy or "inside-out" situations. In this case I don't want the value for "a similar object" back, I want value for "the same object" back.

Happy coding.

---

Thinking about pointers in Python is *wrong*. Values in Python are *objects* and each value represents itself. That is, `x is y` is only true when `x` and `y` evaluate to *the same object*. When objects are passed in python this same concept holds -- the *object itself* is passed. No need to think about references.

Python is [Call-by-Sharing/Call-by-Object-Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) although the term ["Call-By-Reference"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) -- which exists in the "official documentation places" -- is often incorrectly used to describe the behavior (perhaps to "ease" the transition from other languages where the term is also often incorrectly used).

Comment: but when in python do you ever need to do this?  I can't think of a single instance.  Since EVERYTHING is a pointer, you should never have to worry about this.

Comment: @Garret Berg the only time I can recall using object-identity comparisons is for an object cache. I don't want the value for "a similar object" back, I want value for "the same object back".

Comment: @Garrett: Identity testing is usually faster than equality testing (that's why `a is None` is better than `a == None`). Also, there are no pointers in Python.

Comment: Everything is a reference (not pointer), which is exactly why you would want to use this. Everything is a reference, so you cannot just dereference the pointer and check for object-identity directly. Sometimes, you know that two objects will have the same value, but you want to make sure that they are actually references to the same object.

Comment: As pst says, the main use case is when you want to store additional info about a *particular* instance, and don't actually care about the value of that instance.

Answer (score 4):

There is a huge difference the two. `is` tests for object **identity** and `==` tests for **equality**.

Consider this simple example:

```
print [] == []     # True
print [] is []     # False
```

Comment: Yeah, sure. And felt like it'd would be helpful to show the difference betweend the two with a simple example.

Comment: +1 I think it's a pretty good example. Each `[]` creates a new object. Would be nice to see it expanded on `x = []` and with same tests but on `x`.